# POST body of API as direct string text

Tags: c#, api, dotnet-httpclient

just wanna know, Is there a way to Post body of API as string text directly instead of using and making classes for inputs?(I used this way, wanna know is there any other ways?)
thank you

Comment: Yes, it's possible to post plain text.

Comment: @Marco thanks for your answer, even if the API just Approve Json?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @JohanGov yes it will definitely help me, and I will read all of it. tnx for your answer.